# Pointed template type deduced from a nullptr?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, nullptr

Considering the function :

```
template <class T> void f(const T* const ptr);
```

What is `T` for `f(nullptr)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have to answer this with there is none. From § 2.14.7/1 (emphasis mine):

> The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. It is a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. [Note: std::nullptr_t is a distinct type that is **neither a pointer type** nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue of this type is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value.

`T *` would have to be `std::nullptr_t` and since `std::nullptr_t` is **not** a pointer type, that isn't possible. Trying to call it with `nullptr` on GCC 4.7.2 gives an error indicating that it was trying to call `f(std::nullptr_t)`, but only had `f(const T *)`, which agrees with the fact that a `std::nullptr_t` is not a `T *`.